# What folder for temporary exe?

Tags: windows, special-folders

I have created a small exe and associated ini file that we use for diagnostics on customers sites. Customers can go to our website, run a configuration program which downloads the diagnostic exe and ini and sets the exe running.

We do not want to go through a full Windows installation for this as this is overkill for the customers who just want something that will load and start running in 10-15 seconds.

Where should we download this exe to and run according to Windows philosophy and where it is guaranteed to work? The following conditions are essential:

1. A customer doing this may be an administrator on the machine but may also be a basic user.
2. UAC may be switched on.
3. Also during the course of the procedure the user might change.
4. The exe also needs to be able to write to its ini when it first starts.
5. The OS could be XP, Vista, Win7 32-bit, Win7 64-bit

If there is one folder that covers all of the above then fantastic but I'd also be happy to use an appropriate different folder for each of the OS's named.

Comment: This proposed software behaves like malware and will be treated accordingly. Instead just offer to download a ZIP file to the desktop and let the user start it.

Comment: The user might change i.e. from Bob to Mary. So basically it can't be put in a place which is user specific.

Comment: There is no folder in a standard installation that is writable by multiple users.

Comment: @SLaks you are wrong, `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%` (`C:\ProgramData` in my current system) in windows is writeable by anyone in the `User` group. And i'm pretty sure i've used `%ALLUSERSAPPDATA%` (`C:\Documents and Settings\All Users`) in WinXP too. Look at my answer.

Comment: @KurzedMetal: Not in my installation.

Answer (score 0):

In the folder pointed by `%APPDATA%` environment variable which is inside the user profile directory (`%USERPROFILE%`), if it is supposed to be used by any user then `%ALLUSERSAPPDATA%` which is inside `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%`

Take a look at [Recognized Environment Variables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749104%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: That's per-user which contravenes item 3 in the list

Comment: Is %ALLUSERSAPPDATA% applicable to XP as well as Vista and Win7?

Comment: No `%ALLUSERSAPPDATA%` isn't working in my Win7 system. but `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%` does work and is pointing to `C:\ProgramData` which is readable and writable by anyone. It seems that windows 7 moved the `All Users` profile to that folder.

Comment: That's great! I'll write something into the install app that looks first for %ALLUSERSPROFILE% and if that doesn't exist then %ALLUSERSAPPDATA%. Then try it out on XP, Vista, Win7 - as admin and as basic user, with and without UAC switched on. Anyone think that MS have tied themselves into a (not very secure) knot with their security?!